# Why Linq query from DbContext don't return any data to Entity from table-valued function with parameters

Tags: sql-server, linq, mvvm, asp.net-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am tried to use `.FromSqlRaw` and `.FromSqlInterpolated` in ASP.NET Core 3.1, EntityFramework Core 3.1, DotVVM, SQL Server.

```
var result = SomeDbContext
            .SomeModels
            .FromSqlRaw("Select [column1], [column2] From [schema].[ufnTableValueFunction] (@FirstParam, @SecondParam, @ThirdParam)",
                           parameters: new[] { firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam })
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();

var result = SomeDbContext
            .SomeModels
            .FromSqlInterpolated($"select * from [schema].[ufnTableValueFunction] ({firstParam},{secondParam},{thirdParam})")
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();
```

When I use SQL Server Profiler, I find this generated SQL from application and I try use it in database, it is returned data to me. In application no data returned into result. In second application with same system of selecting data with table-valued function all is working fine. What I must do for successful selecting data?

Comment: Both of provided examples won't work?

Comment: Yes, both of examples.

Comment: Can you please add actual entity model and `ufnTableValueFunction`?

Comment: I already know, where the problem was: I had not null properties in the class and the function also returned null values. Thank you for your time.